# Contact form that adds Items dynamically with a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

The form, except the usuall name, phone, email fields etc. I want it to have a dropdown with some products and a text box for the quantity.The point is that i want the user to be able to add more products(dropdown and text box for quantity) with a button. 
  I managed to do that with some Jquery script but when i send the email with  php, the products that i add are not on the email that has been sent.

Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title></title>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body >

  <form name="form1" id="form1" action="mail.php" method="POST">
Όνομα: <input type="text" name="name" size="20">
     <br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="20"> <br>
 Νομός: <input type="text" name="nomos" size="20">
     <br>
Περιοχή: <input type="text" name="perioxh" size="15">
     <br>
Διέυθυνση <input type="text" name="address" size="15">
<br>     
Τηλέφωνο: <input type="text" name="tel" size="9">
<br>  
Δ.Ο.Υ: <input type="text" name="doy" size="9"> 

   <div class="aromatika"> 

     <div class="fotodiv"><img src="images/enoikiazomena-diamerismata-                                                                                                                                                       tinos-crystal-view-exwterikos-xwros-nuxta-1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px"></div>

     <div class="input_wrap">
        <select size="1" name="dropdown">      
        <option selected disabled>ΔΙΑΛΕΞΤΕ ΦΥΤΟ </option>

        <option value="ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17</option>
        <option value="ΣΕΛΙΝΟ Φ17"> ΣΕΛΙΝΟ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17"> ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17"> ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17 </option>
        <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17   </option>
        <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17 </option>              
        </select>
        <div class="posotita">

         Ποσοτητα <input type="text" size="1" name="text[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-info">Προσθέστε προιόν</button>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Αποστολή">      
</form>
    <div></div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now the javascript :

```
    var wrapper = $(".input_wrap>div");
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

        $(add_button).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(wrapper).after('<div class="input_wrap"><select size="1" name="dropdown"><option selected disabled>ΔΙΑΛΕΞΤΕ ΦΥΤΟ </option>
            <option value="ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17</option>
            <option value="selino"> ΣΕΛΙΝΟ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17"> ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17"> ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17 </option>
            <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17   </option><option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17 </option></select>
<a href="#" class="remove_field"> Αφαίρεση Προιόντος</a><div class="posotita">Ποσοτητα <input type="text" name="text[]" size="1" class="form-control">'); //add input box

        });

        $(document).on("click",".remove_field",function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
```

And last the php :

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nomos = $_POST['nomos'];
$perioxh = $_POST['perioxh'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$doy = $_POST['doy'];
$dropdown = $_POST['dropdown'];
$posotita = $_POST['text[]'];
$formcontent=" Όνομα: $name \n Email: $email \n Νομός: $nomos \n Περιοχή: $perioxh \n Διέυθυνση: $address \n Τηλέφωνο: $tel \n Δ.Ο.Υ: $doy \n Προίοντα: $dropdown \n Ποσότητα: $posotita";
$recipient = "info@birdycreative.gr";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

You can see it online at http://birdycreative.gr/jqueryform.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kalimera!

A fix to your question would be the following.

This will give you all your products in separate line along with their quantities:

**HTML & JavaScript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title></title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body >

<form name="form1" id="form1" action="mail.php" method="POST">
    Όνομα: <input type="text" name="name" size="20">
    <br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="20"> <br>
    Νομός: <input type="text" name="nomos" size="20">
    <br>
    Περιοχή: <input type="text" name="perioxh" size="15">
    <br>
    Διέυθυνση <input type="text" name="address" size="15">
    <br>
    Τηλέφωνο: <input type="text" name="tel" size="9">
    <br>
    Δ.Ο.Υ: <input type="text" name="doy" size="9">

    <div class="aromatika">

        <div class="fotodiv">
        <div class="input_wrap">
            <select name="dropdown[0]">
                <option selected disabled>ΔΙΑΛΕΞΤΕ ΦΥΤΟ </option>
                <option value="ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17</option>
                <option value="ΣΕΛΙΝΟ Φ17"> ΣΕΛΙΝΟ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17"> ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17"> ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17 </option>
                <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17   </option>
                <option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17 </option>
            </select>
            <div class="posotita">
                Ποσοτητα <input type="text" size="1" name="text[0]" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-info">Προσθέστε προιόν</button>
    </div>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Αποστολή">
</form>
<div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var wrapper = $(".input_wrap>div");
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button");
    var i = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="input_wrap"><select size="1" name="dropdown[' + i + ']"><option selected disabled>ΔΙΑΛΕΞΤΕ ΦΥΤΟ </option>' +
                '<option value="ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΝΗΘΟΣ Φ17</option>' +
                '<option value="ΣΕΛΙΝΟ Φ17"> ΣΕΛΙΝΟ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΜΑΪΝΤΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΜΠΑΡΟΡΙΖΑ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17"> ΑΡΤΕΜΙΣΙΑ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17"> ΑΠΗΓΑΝΟΣ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17"> ΒΑΣΙΛΙΚΟΣ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17"> ΔΥΟΣΜΟΣ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ Φ17 </option>' +
                '<option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17   </option><option value="ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17"> ΔΕΝΤΡΟΛΙΒΑΝΟ ΗΜΙΕΡΠΟΝ Φ17 </option></select>' +
                '<a href="#" class="remove_field"> Αφαίρεση Προιόντος</a><div class="posotita">Ποσοτητα <input type="text" name="text[' + i + ']" size="1" class="form-control">'
        );
        i++;
    });

    $(document).on("click",".remove_field",function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nomos = $_POST['nomos'];
$perioxh = $_POST['perioxh'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$doy = $_POST['doy'];

$productsArray=[];
foreach (($_POST['dropdown']) as $key => $dropdown) {
    $productsArray[$key] = 'Προϊον: ' . $dropdown . ' - Ποσότητα: ' . $_POST['text'][$key] . " \n ";
}

$productsString = implode('',$productsArray);
$formcontent=" Όνομα: $name \n Email: $email \n Νομός: $nomos \n Περιοχή: $perioxh \n Διέυθυνση: $address \n Τηλέφωνο: $tel \n Δ.Ο.Υ: $doy \n " . $productsString;

$recipient = "info@birdycreative.gr";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its working partially.The quantities are showing seperated with comma but about products, its showing only the first i selected. I took a screenshot [link](http://prnt.sc/dfmgr5) . Na sai kala file euxaristw.

Comment: Answer updated! This should now bring the full list of products and their quantities in separated lines.